# jQuery .next() is adding class to all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap 4 Carousel and I am trying to add a class to the `<a>` elements when the slider changes. I am able to add the class `.highlight` but it adds it to every next `<a>` elements.

The other part of my function that removes the `.highlight` class from the `<a>` tag ONCE but does not replicate on the other two slides when the slide changes again.

I have looked up jQuery documentation and I even closely followed another response to a similar question on StackOverflow with no luck.

So when the Bootstrap slider changes, it removes the class as intended just once and adds the highlight class to the next two elements instead of just one. When the bootstrap slider changes again it does not remove the class and the last two elements stay highlighted. I want just one highlighted at a time and when it changes, to remove the highlight and apply it to the next one.

I genuinely want to understand where my logic is flawed and find a solution so I am adding comments next to my code to explain my thought process. I appreciate the help.

```js
$("#carouselExampleIndicators").on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
  var currentSlide = $('.feature-box'); //I set a variable for the .feature-box class that is the containing div that shares space with the highlight class
  currentSlide.removeClass("highlight"); //I am trying to remove the highlight class from the current .feature-box slide it works once but does not happen again when the slide changes
  currentSlide.next().addClass("highlight"); //I thought this would select the NEXT element (just one) and add the class highlight - instead it chooses the BOTH of the NEXT elements and adds the class
});
```

```css
.highlight a {
  color: #FFF !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/LAaSoL0LrYs/1920x1080')">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h2 class="display-4">First Slide</h2>
        <p class="lead">This is a description for the first slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/bF2vsubyHcQ/1920x1080')">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h2 class="display-4">Second Slide</h2>
        <p class="lead">This is a description for the second slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/szFUQoyvrxM/1920x1080')">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h2 class="display-4">Third Slide</h2>
        <p class="lead">This is a description for the third slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row this-row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 feature-box highlight">
          <a data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active carousel-slide">01 This is another article name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 feature-box">
          <a data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1" class="carousel-slide">02 This is yet another article name to promote it</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 feature-box">
          <a data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2" class="carousel-slide">I am the last of my kind but I too am a article</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok... so... If you have a collection of 5 elements stored in a variable, and then say, for each item in this collection, select the "next" item, wouldn't you expect it to select all but the first item, resulting in a collection of 4 elements? You didn't specify *which* item you wanted to select the next element of, so it did so for all of the items.

Comment: @KevinB I did try using $(this) at one point but I was unable to get the class to move. I'm not sure how to tell it to just choose the *next item*

Comment: To further elaborate if I try .next('.feature-box') it still highlights all of them

Comment: I would assume according to the documentation that selecting all of them would be .nextAll() not .next()

Comment: you are correct, but, if you already have them all selected, what do you expect .next to do? (it’s gonna select all of the ones that have a previous sibling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking jquery to take next sibling after all 3 .feature-box divs. Instead consider below code

```js
$("#carouselExampleIndicators").on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e){
  console.log(e.to);
  $('.feature-box.highlight').removeClass('highlight')
  $('.feature-box').eq(e.to).addClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
.highlight a {
  color: #C00 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/LAaSoL0LrYs/1920x1080')">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h2 class="display-4">First Slide</h2>
        <p class="lead">This is a description for the first slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/bF2vsubyHcQ/1920x1080')">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h2 class="display-4">Second Slide</h2>
        <p class="lead">This is a description for the second slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/szFUQoyvrxM/1920x1080')">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h2 class="display-4">Third Slide</h2>
        <p class="lead">This is a description for the third slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row this-row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 feature-box highlight">
          <a data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active carousel-slide">01 This is another article name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 feature-box">
          <a data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1" class="carousel-slide">02 This is yet another article name to promote it</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 feature-box">
          <a data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2" class="carousel-slide">I am the last of my kind but I too am a article</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## UPDATE

`slide.bs.carousel` event is fired each time bootsrap carousel plugin slides, where it provides to callback event argument (an object) that holds `from` and `to` number attributes telling callback from and to which slide it made transition.

As I mentioned at the top of answer, in your question `$('.feature-box')` will select all 3 divs with matched class `feature-box`. Any jquery function that you call on this context (3 divs) will be performed over that context. So if you call `next()` function, it will try to find next sibling to ALL 3 SELECTED DIVS.

Since by requirements only one `feature-box` can have `highlighted` class we first remove it from all 3 divs (even tho only one has it, it is safe to do so like in code above) then we filter `$(".feature-box")` result with `.eq(to)` so result is now only a div that is at same position as the current slide is. And finally `.addClass("highlighted")` will set that class on filtered result (single div).

I hope this explains better what is going on in that callback.

Comment: I see how .feature-box.highlight helps with this problem but it doesn't seem to help if you were to go BACK to an indicator. I'm not sure whether that's an issue with the class being selected or if .next() is not the best way to go about this. Perhaps there's another jQuery selector for this? I'm trying to find a way in the documentation.

Comment: I edited code, didn't tested it but that is it in nutshell.

Comment: That `if()` isn't valid. Is same as `if(!{})`. Not to mention `all.last().eq()` doesn't make sense. Is a collection of one element

Comment: As I said, I didn't tried that code. Anyways, I updated answer and included code snippet.

Comment: Thank you, I chose this as the answer at it solves the problem. I don't understand it unfortunately and will go in the documentation to try and understand further. I don't know why people who felt they knew better were not willing to either provide a answer,  or at least mention jQuery elements to help get me there. My question showed earnest attempts and thought process. I appreciate your help and you're an asset to the community!